# MySQL performance with update

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures

Which approach is faster in MySQL ?
Implementing a binary tree with MySQL and PHP(Codeigniter).

1)  When only one query can update a lots of rows (Insertion of a node in tree using Nested Sets )

2) By using procedure and some if else logic and loops , reducing the number of rows-say, the number of rows to be updated in this approach is half than the previous one. (Implementing the tree with adjacency list - going upward till root and updating each root)

Earlier i had asked this question [binary-tree-using-php-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775720/binary-tree-using-php-mysql#comment12514099_9775720) But didnt get response . Thats why asked this question which somewhat what I have to know atleast.

Please Help Me !

Comment: if the 2nd approach updates half row, it should take less time, but if the procedure and loop logic is implemented in php then the time required may be higher.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the only rows that needs to be updated is apparently faster.

I see no reason though why it cannot be done with one query.

Comment: could you please help me with this question too ???
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775720/binary-tree-using-php-mysql#comment12514099_9775720

Comment: or some resource , how to assess performance of alternative solutions in MySQl

Comment: I can't. There is no real life problem in it. While abstract description can be far from the real needs

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE` is much faster when update a lot of rows in single table, it just rewrites table with new data.

Answer (score 0):

On my MySQL servers, the second approach is the fastest solution even if you use a transaction with many updates.

Comment: I don't know exactly why but I think it comes from the index regeneration.